# Retrieve geographic information via an API with python

Tags: python, gis

I am a beginner in python. I'm trying to create a dictionary in a JSON file that I created before. This dictionary must contain the geometrical TYPE of the elements that I retrieve via an API. I tried with the following code but I have the following error message:

```
with open(filename) as json_file:
    data_raw = json.load(json_file) 
data_events = dict(type=data_raw['type'], features=[])
```

The API looks like this :

```
...
"geometry":{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[
          2.900875,
          48.550178
    ]
 },
...
```

the error I have :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 25, in <module>
KeyError: 'type'
```

What should i do?

Comment: The error means that your JSON doesn't have `'type'` as a key. What a dict do you want to construct?

Comment: to store point geometry entities. Should I use 'geometry' instead of type? Here is a link to the API I used  https://data.iledefrance.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=evenements-publics-cibul&q=&facet=tags&facet=placename&facet=department&facet=region&facet=city&facet=date_start&facet=date_end&facet=pricing_info&facet=updated_at&facet=city_district

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the object that you're attempting to access is assigned to the `geometry` field. These objects are in a list assigned to the `records` field in the outermost object. So you'll need to use `data_raw["records"][(integer index of record you want to access)]["geometry"]["type"]` to access the desired field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What should I mention instead of index integer if I want to retrieve all entities?

Comment: Do you mean the types of all of the entries in records, or accessing the entirety of the records array?

Comment: Yes the types of all entries in records

Comment: Sure, you can do `[record["geometry"]["type"] for record in data_raw["records"]]`. If you want to remove duplicates, you can do `list(set([record["geometry"]["type"] for record in data_raw["records"]]))`.